# Google Adsense ajax

Tags: ajax, adsense

I have google ads not showing based on actual content because my contents are loaded by ajax. My layout is static and i load all my content through ajax. But i can able to duplicate the content statically.

Can i do this? will google bot detect and show ads based on this? does it violate google adsense policy?.

```
<p style='position:absolute;left:-500px;top:0px;width:100px;overflow:hidden;'>  {$google_keywords}</p>
```

How do i solve ajax content issue even if i have same duplicate info in static first time load , duplicate text visible is not good.? now no iframe , anyone have any idea?.

Comment: it appears that Google themselves don't have a clear policy or roadmap as to handling the ajax issue. There used to be "adsense for ajax" but they moved their resources elsewhere. Why won't you try this and tell us if this works. Maybe keywords needed to be provided as you mentioned (possibly in a hidden div)

Answer (score 0):

Google are not keen on heavy AJAX solutions to deliver content; it makes it difficult for them to crawl the page and serve relevant contextual ads, which is bad for you, the advertiser and end users. Providing you implement a solution that isn't radically changing the page layout or content, you can have the ads remain in situ. But it would be better to render a new AdSense impression each time the page "reloads" (ie. when completely new content is displayed).